# Swapping CapsLock key for hyper

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap, xkb, remapping, keys

i tried doing this by running a .Xmodmap script at startup but it just doesn't work, I've seen a lot of threads with people (maybe) fixing it, but i just can't!
I've also seen some threads about using XKB but i can't find any help on how to use that. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of digging, i found this `setxkbmap -option caps:hyper`